# Why my array getting appended instead of clearing and Adding new data

Tags: arrays, reactjs, algorithm, bubble-sort, react-state

I am trying to achieve a method in which the array steps got filled with new data every time I click on the button of Create New array, but instead of that, the data is getting appended instead of updating.

here are my states :

```
const [arr , setArray] = useState(createArray())
const [steps , setSteps] = useState([]);
const [selectedAlgorithm , setSelectedAlgorithm] = useState ();
```

here is my create new Array function :

```
const handleCreateNewData = ()=>{
    let newarr = createArray();
    setArray ([]);
    
    setArray([...newarr]);
    setSteps ([]);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if ( algorithms[selectedAlgorithm] !== undefined){
            algorithms[selectedAlgorithm](arr, steps , setSteps);
            console.log('running')
        }

    },2000)
   
}
```

here is my bubble sort algorithm :

```
export const BubbleSort = (array , steps ,setSteps) =>{
let funarray = new Array();
funarray = [...array] ;
for (let i = 0 ; i < funarray.length-1 ; i++){
    for(let j = 0 ; j < funarray.length-1 ; j++){
        if(funarray[j]>funarray[j+1]){
            [funarray[j],funarray[j+1]] = [funarray[j+1],funarray[j]]
            setSteps([...steps, funarray])
            steps.push(funarray.slice());
            console.log('Working')
        }
    }
}


return funarray;
 }
```

What is supposed to do is every time I click on create new array it should generate a new set of arrays but instead of creating new arrays it just appending the new arrays in the old steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp array to hold the steps, then when the loops are done, call setSteps:

```
const BubbleSort = (array, steps, setSteps) => {
  let funarray = [];
  funarray = [...array];
  let temp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < funarray.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < funarray.length - 1; j++) {
      if (funarray[j] > funarray[j + 1]) {
        [funarray[j], funarray[j + 1]] = [funarray[j + 1], funarray[j]];
        temp.push(funarray)
      }
    }
  }
  setSteps(temp);

  return funarray;
};
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wind-ijj7z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Actually, i m trying to push a new array to steps each time a swap happens, So, if I do this it will create a problem to my app's basic functionality.